# LIKE Query on Postgres JSON array field in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, sql-like, psql

I have a table called `messages` which has a `jsonB` column called `headers` to store message headers. It looks like this:

```
[
   {
      "name":"Cc",
      "field":{
         "name":"Cc",
         "value":"\"abc@gmail.com\" <abc@gmail.com>",
         "length":null,
         "charset":"UTF-8",
         "element":null,
         "address_list":{
            "addresses":[
               {
                  "data":{
                     "raw":"\"abc@gmail.com\" <abc@gmail.com>",
                     "error":null,
                     "group":null,
                     "local":"abc",
                     "domain":"gmail.com",
                     "comments":[

                     ],
                     "display_name":"abc@gmail.com",
                     "obs_domain_list":null
                  },
                  "parsed":true
               }
            ],
            "group_names":[

            ]
         }
      },
      "charset":"UTF-8",
      "field_order_id":14,
      "unparsed_value":"\"abc@gmail.com\" <abc@gmail.com>"
   },
   {
      "name":"Message-ID",
      "field":{
         "name":"Message-ID",
         "uniq":1,
         "value":"<sdasdasd+tkiCVQ@mail.gmail.com>",
         "length":null,
         "charset":"UTF-8",
         "element":{
            "message_ids":[
               "sdasdasd+tkiCVQ@mail.gmail.com"
            ]
         }
      },
      "charset":"UTF-8",
      "field_order_id":16,
      "unparsed_value":"<sdasdasd+tkiCVQ@mail.gmail.com>"
   },
   {
      "name":"Subject",
      "field":{
         "name":"Subject",
         "value":"Re: test email",
         "errors":[

         ],
         "length":null,
         "charset":"UTF-8",
         "element":null
      },
      "charset":"UTF-8",
      "field_order_id":19,
      "unparsed_value":"Re: test email"
   }
]
```

**I want search records where 'name' = 'Subject' and 'unparsed_value' like `%test%` and return the result in Rails 6.0.2?**

I'm trying the below mention code:

```
messages.where("headers @> '[{\"name\": \"Subject\"}, {\"unparsed_value\" LIKE \"%test%\"}]'")
```

But it's throwing error!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a sub query to get the elements you need to compare and then use them in the where clause:

```
Message
  .from(
    Message.select("
      id,
      headers,
      jsonb_array_elements(headers)->>'unparsed_value' AS unparsed_value,
      jsonb_array_elements(headers)->>'name' AS name
    "), :t
  )
  .select('t.*')
  .where("t.name = 'Subject' AND t.unparsed_value LIKE '%test%'")
```

Comment: It's returning empty array!

Comment: @SebastianPalma I believe the headers column in the question contains an array of hashes. Yours contains a single hash.

Comment: Right @LesNightingill, just updated that. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: thanks @LesNightingill. It worked! May I know why it is needed to do self inner query on Message table?

Comment: Not a self inner @Rivu (join?), it's just you need somehow to access those two columns/values to use them in your where clause. The most common is to think you can get them in your select statement, but values there aren't able to be used within the `where`, so `from` is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

The query you need looks like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE 
  (SELECT true FROM jsonb_to_recordset(messages.headers)
    AS x(name text, field jsonb)
    WHERE name = 'Subject'
    AND field->>'unparsed_value' LIKE '%test%');
```

Does this give you the result you're looking for?